# Column names with dots in QuestDB?

Tags: telegraf, questdb, jolokia

I'd like to use the [Jolokia Telegraf](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/jolokia2_agent) plugin to collect JMX metrics and push them to [QuestDB](https://questdb.io/). However, the Jolokia plugin creates tags with dots and QuestDB does not support dots in column names. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Telegraf rename plugin](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/blob/release-1.28/plugins/processors/rename/README.md) to replace the dot with e.g. underscore: `_`

From the rename plugin documentation:

```
# Rename measurements, tags, and fields that pass through this filter.
[[processors.rename]]
  ## Specify one sub-table per rename operation.
  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    measurement = "network_interface_throughput"
    dest = "throughput"

  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    tag = "hostname"
    dest = "host"

  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "lower"
    dest = "min"

  [[processors.rename.replace]]
    field = "upper"
    dest = "max"
```